# Another issue after AngularFire 0.5.0 update - calculation returns NaN

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm more and more disappointed with the angularFire 0.5.0, because nothing works correctly anymore. After I was able to fix the remove of a single item with help of you, I ran into another issue.

Each single item consists of a date, description and price. Before I updated, I was able to calculate the total of all prices and return it on the page. Now it just says NaN or Null. I was already trying to figure out why, but both values (earning.price, $scope.totalEarning) in the calculation are numbers. I don't get it. Does the new angular fire do anything? I'm trying to fix it since a while and just can't. I would be really, if somebody could figure it out. Probably I'm just not seeing it and it's a pretty dumb issue.

See it on plunkr: http://embed.plnkr.co/jb1iWOcjcm0alFchmzOH/preview

Here is the code:

```
$scope.addEarning = function() {
    $scope.earnings.$add({date:$scope.FormEarningDate, description:$scope.FormEarningDescription, price:$scope.FormEarningPrice});    
    $scope.FormEarningDate = '';
    $scope.FormEarningDescription = '';
    $scope.FormEarningPrice = '';
    $scope.updateEarning();
}

$scope.updateEarning = function() {
    $scope.totalEarning = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.earnings, function (earning) {
        price = parseFloat(earning.price)
        $scope.totalEarning += price;
        $log.log(typeof $scope.totalEarning);
    })
    $scope.totalBalance = $scope.totalEarning - $scope.totalCost;
}
```

And the html:

```
<form for="Profit" class="form-inline" style="margin-bottom: 20px" ng-submit="addEarning()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="date" name="idate" ng-model="FormEarningDate" class="form-control" id="idate" placeholder="Date">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" name="idesc" ng-model="FormEarningDescription" required class="form-control" id="idesc" placeholder="Description">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input type="text" name="iprice" ng-model="FormEarningPrice" required class="form-control" id="iprice" placeholder="Amount">
    </div>
</div>




<tr ng-repeat="earning in earnings | orderByPriority | orderBy : 'date'">
    <td>{{earning.date}}</td>
    <td>{{earning.description}}</td>
    <td>{{earning.price}} €</td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="earnings.$remove(earning.$id)">Löschen</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td><strong>Total:</strong> {{totalEarning}} €</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What do you get in the log for $scope.totalEarning? Could you reproduce this in a simple jsfiddle/plunkr?

Comment: For typeof $scope.totalEarning I get number. For $scope.totalEarning I just get NaN.

Comment: Here is a shortened plunkr reproduction: http://embed.plnkr.co/jb1iWOcjcm0alFchmzOH/preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

There are several things you are doing incorrectly.  As stated in my original answer, you need to iterate over the keys from Firebase, not the firebase object itself.  Additionally, you need to ensure all updates happen after Firebase has updated (via an `$on('change', ...)` event handler) and within the AngularJS lifecycle (accomplished below using `$timeout`).

```
var app = angular.module('balance', ['firebase']);
app.controller('BalanceCtrl', function($scope, $log, $http, $timeout, $firebase) {
  $scope.earnings = $firebase(new Firebase('https://dgdemo.firebaseio.com/Earnings'));

  $scope.totalBalance = 'Nothing yet.';
  $scope.totalEarning = 0;
  $scope.totalCost = 0;

  $scope.updateEarning = function() {
    $scope.totalEarning = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.earnings.$getIndex(), function (id) {
      var earning = $scope.earnings[id];
      $scope.totalEarning += parseFloat(earning.price);
    });
    $scope.totalBalance = $scope.totalEarning - $scope.totalCost;
  };
  // Ensure any call to updateCallback will execute within the AngularJS lifecycle.
  var updateCallback = angular.bind(null, $timeout, $scope.updateEarning);

  $scope.addEarning = function() {
    var earning = $scope.earnings.$add({
      date: $scope.FormEarningDate,
      description: $scope.FormEarningDescription,
      price: $scope.FormEarningPrice
    });
    $scope.FormEarningDate = '';
    $scope.FormEarningDescription = '';
    $scope.FormEarningPrice = '';
  };

  $scope.earnings.$on('change', updateCallback);
});
```

**Original Answer**

This is because `angular.forEach` is iterating over all properties of the `$scope.earnings` object (which is a Firebase object).  What you want to do is iterate over the individual items.

```
$scope.updateEarning = function() {
  $scope.totalEarning = 0;
  angular.forEach($scope.earnings.$getIndex(), function (id) {
    var earning = $scope.earnings[id];
    $scope.totalEarning += parseFloat(earning.price);
  });
  $scope.totalBalance = $scope.totalEarning - $scope.totalCost;
}
```

Comment: It seems to work better. Problem is, that it doesn't add the latest item price to the total. It adds the last item price, when I add a new item. And for some reason, it doesn't do the totalBalance anymore. I also get the error now: TypeError: Cannot read property 'price' of undefined

Comment: thank you very much. That makes sense, updating after firebase has updated. It works fine now. :)